# Disable history in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, history

To disable a history in Linux environment I've executed the following commands:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=0
export HISTSIZE=0
unset HISTFILE
```

Is such command combination enough or I have to also execute `history -c` or something else?

Will this keep history disabled even when I reboot a server or such commands need to be executed after reboot again and again?

Comment: You should ask it on [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange branch

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just add this command to a bash startup file which could be `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bashrc` depending your target scope and distro that customizes bash. See the `INVOCATION` section of bash's manual (`man bash`).

```
shopt -u -o history
```

Or

```
set +o history
```

Which would disable history.

Although you have to clear your history once:

```
history -c
```

And also delete your `~/.bash_history` file.

Answer (score 33):

For most usecases, `unset HISTFILE` should be enough.

That disables writing the history file, while it still allows to cycle through the last commands using <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>.
Changing `HISTFILESIZE` doesn't have any effect when you unset `HISTFILE`, as it only affects how many lines will be written to the history file when the shell exits. If set to 0 with `HISTFILE` set, then the file will be truncated to 0 at exit.
Changing `HISTSIZE` changes how many commands the current shell will remember.

To make this changes permanent, `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` are good places to insert the commands.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to persist through reboots, you can add them to `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`.