# disable .bash_history in GNU

Tags: gnu

It is about GNU .bash_history.
Required to disable .bash_history file creation for 2 specific users.
So when those users logging on .bash_history should not be created.

it is required to remove existing .bash_history file for some specific users and this file should never appear back.

Any ideas? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable history in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663078/disable-history-in-linux)

Comment: Can you explain why? If this is not an X-Y-problem http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem then recompiling bash to write the history to another file will work.

Comment: Hi Ole, 
thanks a lot for your response. 
I will elaborate then.
.bash_history is the only .** file in the home directory of a user named "billing" and it is located on a server-X.  Other files located in that home directory are some billing files they are sent to another machine (billing server). Thus that path (home directory) is defined only for billing files and since .bash_history is there the system is generating an alarm about the file which is not transferred to remote billing system.

Comment: There are 2 ways:
1. to make .bash_histroy be generated in some other directory. Not directly under home directory.. it can be some folder under the home directory. then alarm will not be generated. 
/some path/billing/.bash_history - alarm generated
/some path/billing/some folder/.bash_history - alarm NOT generated

2. To switch .bash_history generation for this specific user.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
chmod 0 .bash_history
```

Comment: Hi Ole, thanks a lot for your response.
But unfortunately this just changes the rights of this file. I need to remove this file (.bash_history) forever. It needs to be done for some users and it should never appear. I mean when some specific users logon next time this file should not be generated.